# How do I use ASP.NET pages in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms

I have a site written in C# using the ASP.NET MVC 2 frameworkthat unfortunately requires a few pages to work on Webforms (for a ReportViewer Control that needs Viewstate.

I've created a folder called `Reports`, converted it to a `Web Application` and added a page to the folder called `ReportViewer.aspx` (the system correctly added aspx.cs file and aspx.designer files).

I also created a class called `BasePage.cs` which inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` and made my `ReportViewer.aspx.cs` inherit it.

When I try to browse this page, I get the following error:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   type
>   `AzureWatch.ControlPanel.Web.Reports.ReportViewer`.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  `<%@ Page Language="C#"`
>   `AutoEventWireup="true"`
>   `CodeBehind="ReportViewer.aspx.cs"`
>   `Inherits="AzureWatch.ControlPanel.Web.Reports.ReportViewer"`

How do I get ASP.NET aspx pages to show up in an ASP.NET MVC site correctly?

Comment: Have your created a separate web.config file for "Reports" web application?

Comment: I've just added web.config but nothing has changed

Comment: Are you certain `AzureWatch.ControlPanel.Web.Reports.ReportViewer` is loadable by your Web Form?

Comment: OK, this is a stupid user error... I apologize for even starting the question :(  I was in 'Release' mode which is not working correctly from the VS2010 environment.  As soon as I switched to Debug mode, everything started functioning.  Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use .aspx pages by adding them to your MVC app - MVC is a framework over ASP.NET anyhow, so there is nothing to stop you from adding a .aspx page except your own guilt :)